# Remove routing element in rest api ( Magento )

Tags: magento2, api, wishlist

when i call this api **http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/wishlist/1/3 it works** and wishlist item gets added

but when i call **http://localhost/magento2/rest/all/V1/wishlist/1/3 it does'nt work**

Seems like it has something to do with **"all" in api call or store**

Here is webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/:customerId" method="GET">
        <service class="YourCompany\WishlistWebService\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="getWishlistForCustomer"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/:customerId/:productId" method="POST">
        <service class="YourCompany\WishlistWebService\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="addWishlistForCustomer"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/:customerId/:productId" method="DELETE">
        <service class="YourCompany\WishlistWebService\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="removeItem"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>


<?php
/**
 * A Magento 2 module named YourCompany/WishlistWebService
 *
 */
namespace YourCompany\WishlistWebService\Model;

use YourCompany\WishlistWebService\Api\WishlistManagementInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProvider;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item as ItemResource;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation as AppEmulation;
/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the WishlistManagementInterface
 */
class WishlistManagement implements WishlistManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Wishlist item collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection
     */
    protected $_itemCollection;

        /**
     * @var ItemResource
     */
    private $itemResource;
    /**
     * @var WishlistRepository
     */
    protected $_wishlistRepository;
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    protected $_wishlistResource;
    /**
     * @var WishlistFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistFactory;

    /**
     * @var Item
     */
    protected $_itemFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
     */
    protected $_customer;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $productImageHelper;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storemanagerinterface;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
     */
    protected $appEmulation;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_productload;
    protected $_wishlistObj;
    /**
     *@var \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory
     */
    protected $countryfactory;
    protected $_productloader;
    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param ItemResource $itemResource
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistObj,
        CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory,
        WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        AppEmulation $appEmulation,
        ItemResource $itemResource,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryfactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanagerinterface,
        ProductImageHelper $productImageHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productload,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlist $wishlistResource,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $_wishlistCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
        $this->_wishlistObj = $wishlistObj;
        $this->countryfactory = $countryfactory;
        $this->storemanagerinterface = $storemanagerinterface;
        $this->_itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_productload = $productload;
        $this->_wishlistResource = $wishlistResource;
        $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
        $this->productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->itemResource = $itemResource;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
        $this->_wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Get wishlist collection
     * @deprecated
     * @param $customerId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId)
    {
       
        if (empty($customerId) || !isset($customerId) || $customerId == "") {
            throw new InputException(__('Id required'));
        } else {
                
            $collection =
            $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId)->getData();
            
            $baseurl = $this->storemanagerinterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';
           
            $wishlistData = [];
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $productInfo = $this->_productloader->create()->load($item['product_id']);
                $imageURL = $this->getImageUrl($productInfo, 'product_base_image');
                if ($productInfo['small_image'] == 'no_selection') {
                    $currentproduct = $this->_productload->load($productInfo['entity_id']);
                    $imageURL = $this->getImageUrl($productInfo, 'product_base_image');
                    $productInfo['small_image'] = $imageURL;
                    $productInfo['thumbnail'] = $imageURL;
                }else{
                    $imageURL = $baseurl.$productInfo['small_image'];
                    $productInfo['small_image'] = $imageURL;
                    $productInfo['thumbnail'] = $imageURL;
                }
                $data = [
                    "wishlist_item_id" => $item['wishlist_item_id'],
                    "wishlist_id"      => $item['wishlist_id'],
                    "product_id"       => $item['product_id'],
                    "store_id"         => $item['store_id'],
                    "added_at"         => $item['added_at'],
                    "description"      => $item['description'],
                    "qty"              => round($item['qty']),
                ];

                $wishlistData[] = $data;
            }
            return $wishlistData;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Add wishlist item for the customer
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param int $productId
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {
        if ($productId == null) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__
            ('Invalid product, Please select a valid product'));
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
        try {
          
          $wishlist = $this->_wishlistObj->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
            $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
            $wishlist->save();
            return $wishlist->getData();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Helper function that provides full cache image url
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageUrl($product, string $imageType = ''){
        $storeId = $this->storemanagerinterface->getStore()->getId();
        $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
        $imageUrl = $this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, $imageType)->getUrl();
        $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

        return $imageUrl;
    }
    public function removeItem($customerId, $productId)
    {
        $wishlist = $this->_wishlistObj->create();
        $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);

        if (!$wishlist->getId()) {
            $wishlist->setCustomerId($customerId);
            $wishlist->getResource()->save($wishlist);
        }

        
        $item = $wishlist->getItem($productId);
        if (!$item) {
            return false;
        }

         $this->itemResource->delete($item); 

        return true;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts how to remove "all" from api ?